# fetchmany(1) breaks after UPDATE

Tags: sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

I'm writing a python + sqlite3 database management function, where every "sell" in the system must be done only if there's enough units of the product, and every "supply" could be done any time.

I'm trying to make a database query and fetch a line, then update one entry of it and using the same table to fetch the next line.
All updates should be visible for the next lines query. for some reason (which i don't understand and would be happy to) a `cursor.Execute(#some update#)` would break the previous `cursor.fetchmany(1)`, and that would conclude in exiting the while loop.

here's the code:

```
def act():
    selection = """SELECT Products_tab.quantity as old_quantity, 
                    Activities_tab.quantity as new_quantity, 
                    Products_tab.id
                    FROM Products_tab inner join Activities_tab on 
                    Products_tab.id=Activities_tab.product_id"""
    cursor.execute(selection)

    while True:
        row_list = cursor.fetchmany(1)
        if row_list:
            quantity = row_list[0][0]
            change_amount = row_list[0][1]
            new_quantity = quantity + change_amount
            product_id = row_list[0][2]
            if change_amount < 0:  # sell
                if new_quantity >= 0:           # just to check if sell is possible
                    cursor.execute("""UPDATE Products_tab SET quantity=({})
                                WHERE id = ({})""".format(new_quantity, product_id))
        else:
            break
```

I would like to understand why it's happening (since I couldn't find any info online), and how to solve it.
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, the issue involves your handling of cursors. Consider breaking them up and be sure to use parameterization:

```
# USE TWO CURSORS
sel_cursor = conn.cursor()     
upd_cursor = conn.cursor()

selection = ...

while True: 
   sel_cursor.execute(selection)         # MOVE INSIDE LOOP
   row_list = cursor.fetchmany(1) 

   if row_list: 
       ...
       # ACTION QUERY WITH PARAMS
       upd_cursor.execute("""UPDATE Products_tab 
                             SET quantity = ? WHERE id = ?""", 
                          [new_quantity, product_id])
       conn.commit()
   else:
       break
```

However, avoid the loop and Python parameters and run **one** pure SQL with its set-based efficiency. Because SQLite does not support `UPATE...JOIN` or `UPDATE...FROM`, subqueries are used multiple times including `CASE` logic to correlate the product quantities across both tables.

```sql
UPDATE Products_tab p
SET p.quantity = CASE
                    WHEN (SELECT quantity
                          FROM Activities_tab
                          WHERE product_id = p.id) < 0
                          AND
                         (p.quantity + (SELECT quantity
                                        FROM Activities_tab
                                        WHERE product_id = p.id)) >= 0
                    THEN (p.quantity + (SELECT quantity
                                        FROM Activities_tab
                                        WHERE product_id = p.id)) 
                    ELSE p.quantity
                 END
WHERE p.ID IN
   (SELECT product_id 
    FROM Activities_tab)
```